# function inside page not working correctly after using load() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

im using jquery tab as example
i have an index.php

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and the custom.js : load page.php **only after navigation click**, by default the #content is blank

```
$(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});
// clicked event below
$('#content').load(page.php) // load only when clicked
```

page.php : the page.php load successfully but the tabs inside the page is not displaying correctly and all the function not working because im using .load()

```
<div id="tabs">
tabs data etc..
</div>
```

so my question is:
1. is there a way to reload the custom.js(file) after using .load() function? or
2. is there a way without writing the bunch of jquery code into script tag on the page.php? or
3. is there any better way doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trigger an event in the load callback and listen for that in document ready.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('ContentsLoadedEvent', function(){
        $('#tabs').tabs();
    });
});

$('#contents').load('http://localhost/page.php', function() {
    $(document).trigger($.Event('ContentsLoadedEvent'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are initializing jquery tabs when page is full loaded(but your html is not available that time because you are loading content via ajax after page is loaded),so you have to initialize jquery tabs plugin after html is rendered on page by load call, you have to use load success callback:

```
$('#content').load("page.php",function(){

   $('#tabs').tabs();

});
```